# Using scanf() get an int and some strings?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am using `scanf` to read a integer n and then read n strings. But it seems does not work. Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1000
#define MAX_LEN 81

char str[MAX][MAX_LEN];
int a,i;


int main()
{
        scanf("%d", &a);
        for (i=0; i<a; ++i) {
                scanf("%[^\n]", str[i]);
        }

        for (i=0; i<a; ++i)
                printf("%s\n", str[i]);

}
```

Using `%[^\n]` I want to a sentence into a single string.
What is the problem?

update:
 I want to input like this:

```
 4
 one 
 two
 THREE three
 FOUR four
```

But in fact, when I input a "4", the program then output 4 blank lines and then exits.

```
[walle@centos64 ~]$ ./a.out
4
_
_
_
_
```

where the output I expected is like this:

```
[walle@centos64 ~]$ ./a.out
4
one
two
THREE three
FOUR four
```

thans.

Comment: Examples of `input` , `current output` and `expected output` will help clarify your statement

Comment: You need to swallow the `\n` after each `scanf()`, using e.g. `getchar()`.

Comment: @Paul R, thanks to your reply. Can you explain a lot? Why there is no need to "swallow" when I use "%s" format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add a space before specifier in `scanf`. It will consume `\n` left in stdin and will make you able to give second input and so on.

Change to `scanf(" %[^\n]", str[i]);` and `printf(" %s\n", str[i]);`

Notice the space given in `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgets` other than `scanf` to get input lines. An extra `getchar` is there to consume the new line after inputting the integer `n`.

```
scanf("%d", &a);
getchar();
for (i=0; i<a; ++i) {
        fgets(str[i], sizeof(str[i]), stdin);
}

for (i=0; i<a; ++i)
        printf("%s", str[i]);
```

Note that `fgets` would store the new line in the string as well. Remove it if you don't need it.

Comment: that won't work for the input, which i have updated in my questions. thanks.

Comment: @FeiXue Yeah, I posted the answer before seeing your edit. Take a look at this version using `fgets`.

Comment: @FeiXue Did you know that [`scanf` is dangerous and should be avoided](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)? Even in the first part of your program where you use `scanf` to get the integer `n`. It's better to do it with `fgets` and `sscanf`, as it would be more robust.

Comment: thank you. I know `scanf` may has some problems. But in my situation it's safe and suited. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1000
#define MAX_LEN 81

char str[MAX][MAX_LEN];
int a,i;


int main()
{
        scanf("%d", &a);
        for (i=0; i<a; ++i) {
                scanf("%s[^\n]", str[i]);
                /* scanf("%s", str[i]);*/        /*this line is also OK */
        }

        for (i=0; i<a; ++i)
                printf("%s\n", str[i]);

}


$ gcc -g t.c
$ ./a.out 
2
one
two
one
two
```

you missed 's' in "%s[^\n]" before "[^\n]".

Comment: That won't work if your input contains white space, as the example in the question.

Comment: `scanf("%s[^\n]", str[i])` is certainly wrong.  Suggest `scanf(" %[^\n]", str[i])`.